# Create Powershell GUI with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I am using Visual Studio to create a GUI environment for all my PowerShell scripts together to create a common platform . I have one problem with the text box . I want to have a text box so all the results appear there . Right now only the last command is appearing there .

Any suggestions ?

```
 <TextBox  x:Name="Information" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,116,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="255" Width="678"/>
```

and I want at this texbox to appear the following messages

```
$WPFMapping.Add_Click({
    {
        $WPFInformation.Text = " We Will try to map the drives"}
    if (((New-Object System.IO.DriveInfo("N:")).DriveType -ne
    "NoRootDirectory"))
    {
        $WPFInformation.Text = " N drive is already mounted and accessible"}
    else {
        net use /persistent:yes N: "this drive"
        Write-Host     "mounting"}
    if (((New-Object System.IO.DriveInfo("V:")).DriveType -ne
    "NoRootDirectory"))
    {
        $WPFInformation.Text = " V drive is already mounted and accessible"}
    else  {
        $WPFInformation.Text = " V drive mapping in progress"}
    net use /persistent:yes V: "this drive"
    $WPFInformation.Text = " V drive mapping has been completed"
})
```

Comment: Any code you can share?

Comment: Without showing the relevant parts of your code, I doubt if anyone will be able to answer this..

Comment: I will try to share a part of the code but I don't know if it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the text in `$WPFInformation.Text` for the second drive mapping (`V:`), you overwrite the text you have set in there earlier for the `N:` mapping.

To append extra lines to the textbox, use

```
$WPFInformation.Text += [Environment]::NewLine
$WPFInformation.Text += " V drive is already mounted and accessible"
```

etc. for every next line you want to add.

You can also use `AppendText()` to add the new lines in there:

```
$WPFInformation.AppendText("`r`n V drive is already mounted and accessible")
```

Where **`r`n** represents the `CRLF` newline.

p.s. Of course, make sure the textbox's MultiLine property is set to `$WPFInformation.Multiline = $true`